# Python JSONDecode Error because a number starts with 0

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to load a json file using requests and I am getting an error

```
>>> r = requests.get('urlto.json').json()

JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter or '}': line 11 column 418 (char 6232)
```

This is the json in question:

```
{"Resource Name":"","Contact Name":null,"Contact Email":null,"Primary Phone":"","Primary Phone Ext":null,"Alternate Phone":null,"Alternate Phone Ext":null,"TTY":null,"Website URL":"","Website Tiny URL":null,"Website Name":null,"Email":"","Street Address":"","Street Address 2":null,"City":"","State":"MA","Postal Code":01331,"Description":null,"Category":null,"Tags":null,"Notes":null,"Services":null,"Longitude":null,"Latitude":null,"Thumbnail":null},
```

The problem is that the postal code starts with a 0. The other postal codes that come before this don't throw an error. If I quote that postal code, it doesn't throw an error. How can I get around this?

Comment: You should quote postal codes.  Postal codes are not always numeric, especially in countries outside the US.

Comment: Also, even if that parsed correctly, it would come back out as the integer 1,331, or '1331'. Which isn't a valid postal code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see now that it is invalid json. Thank you

How do I close/delete this question?